# global name 'request' is not defined

Tags: python, django, session

When using the example **"views.py without functions.py"**, it is working **fine** and session is being checked alright, so it returns the username.

But, when using the second example, **with the functions.py**, is showing me the following **error**

> NameError at /login/
>
> global name 'request' is not defined

**views.py without functions.py**

```
def main(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    if request.session.get('username'):
        susername = request.session['username']
    else:
        susername = ""

    return render_to_response("login/login.html",{'username': susername},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**views.py with functions.py**

```
def main(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    susername = loggedin()


    return render_to_response("login/login.html",{'username': susername},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**functions.py**

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def loggedin():
    if request.session.get('username'):
        susername = request.session['username']
    else:
        susername = ""

    return susername
```

Why is second one not working and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are writing is a template context processor, and you should write it like this:

```
def loggedin(request):
    return {'username': request.session.get('username','')}
```

Save it in a file, and add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py` after the `'django.core.context_processors.request',` line.

If you named the file as `someapp/processors.py`, then you'll add `'somapp.processors.loggedin',` to the tuple.

Then, as long as you are returning an instance of `RequestContext`, you'll have `{{ username }}` in your templates.

Comment: +1 While this is a good approach, I think the OP is trying out a simple tutorial, in which he just forgot to send the request object as a parameter.

Comment: +1 Wow, this what better than what I was looking for. Actually, I wondered if that would be possible in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it. Request is not passed as an argument, therefore it is unknown in the scope of the `loggedin()` function.

You can simply pass the request like

```
susername = loggedin(request)
```

Or, in this case, just pass what you need to check.

```
susername = loggedin(request.session)
```

And change the function to

```
def loggedin(session):
    return session['username'] if session.get('username') else ''
```

Comment: `return session.get('username', '')` would be better, but at least the code will work now.